# Comparing two JSON objects from input AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, drag-and-drop

I'm using this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/NLQGL/2/) but with some modifications. I've added input methods to my app, so user can choose any json file from local pc and read it on a page then choose one more file compare it and see results on the bottom page. 
But I'm getting every time error

```
document.getElementById(...).forEach is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong? Below my code.. and not working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLQGL/23/) with the error:

```
app.controller("Main",function ($scope) {

    // ===== Start FileReader =====

    $scope.leftWindow = function readSingleLeftFile(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        if (!file) {
            return;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var leftcontent = e.target.result;
            displayLeftContents(leftcontent);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    };
    function displayLeftContents(leftcontent) {
        $scope.leftElement = document.getElementById('left-content');
        $scope.leftElement.innerHTML = leftcontent;
    }
    document.getElementById('left-input')
        .addEventListener('change', $scope.leftWindow, false);

    $scope.rightWindow = function readSingleRightFile(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        if (!file) {
            return;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var rightcontent = e.target.result;
            displayRightContents(rightcontent)

        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    };
    function displayRightContents(rightcontent) {
        $scope.rightElement = document.getElementById('right-content');
        $scope.rightElement.innerHTML = rightcontent;
    }
    document.getElementById('right-input')
        .addEventListener('change', $scope.rightWindow, false);

    // ===== End FileReader =====

    $scope.results = (function(){
        var leftInputIds = {};
        var rightInputIds = {};
        var result = [];

        document.getElementById('left-input').forEach(function (el, i) {
            leftInputIds[el.id] = document.getElementById('left-input')[i];
        });

        document.getElementById('right-input').forEach(function (el, i) {
            rightInputIds[el.id] = document.getElementById('right-input')[i];
        });

        for (var i in rightInputIds) {
            if (!leftInputIds.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                result.push(rightInputIds[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }());
});
```

and div

```
<section ng-show="dnd">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="childGrid" style="display: flex">
                        <div style="width: 50%">
                            <input type="file" id="left-input"/>
                            <h3>Contents of the file:</h3>
                            <pre id="left-content"></pre>
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 50%">
                            <input type="file" id="right-input"/>
                            <h3>Contents of the file:</h3>
                            <pre id="right-content"></pre>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="parentGrid">
                        <div id="compare">
                            {{results|json}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: There should never be any dom code in  controller. Your data model should drive the view...not the other way around. All of your adjustments are starting from the wrong place

Comment: @charlietfl, please could you define more deep?

Comment: Yes...you should not be using things like `getElementById` in controller. You should be modifying your data model and using template to render the dom based on the data model

Comment: Why do you think you need a forEach? You only have one valid element on the page with that id.

Comment: @KevinB because each Json objects consists from multiple arrays inside

Comment: but.... dom elements aren't json objects. hell, json objects aren't even a thing for that matter, JSON is a string format, not an object, array, or anything else. it's just a string.

Comment: @charlietfl I've got your idea, and the answer of RIYAJ KHAN below confirmed it. I used the next code:      console.log(leftInput);

        var leftInput =  document.getElementById('left-content');
        leftInputIds[leftInput.id] = leftInput; and nothing happened, I believe the problem is that it starts to compare early then Json  files has been loaded. console.log  certainly says underfined cause nothing has been loaded too

Comment: @KevinB Ok, What is your suggestion? I know that is only string.. but how do you compare it with other 'just a string'?

Comment: First off i don't know what you're tryign to compair against. trying to use .forEach on a method that only returns a single dom element makes no sense. That dom element isn't json, it's a dom element, so again i don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @KevinB thru input, on a page, is rendered two json files almost identical with around 15000 lines, I need to compare it and show diff... if you can't understand why am I using forEach, just tell your solution, I open to discussion

Comment: I still don't understand why you are using forEach. do you have multiple rows? because if you have only one row, there's no need for forEach. if you have multiple rows, getElementById isn't going to work. there's quite a bit wrong with your code, including the fact that you're accessing the DOM from within a controller..

Comment: @KevinB In my case, I have an array of highly nested objects

Comment: Right, but you haven't even retrieved the json string yet, you're still failing to get the json string from the dom node! (which, to be fair, you shouldn't even have to do if you're using angular. I think you're going about this all wrong.)

Comment: @KevinB finally man, now I got you. So before comparing I have to stringify JSON from dom element, and after that only compare, right?

Comment: well, you have to convert the json string from a string to a javascript object (JSON.parse). but... why not skip putting it in the dom and store the object on the scope in the first place? then you don't have to do any parsing/stringifying back and forth, and you don't have to touch the DOM.

Comment: @KevinB what do you mean by "store the object in the first place"?

Comment: When you get the string from the reader, parse it and store it on the scope, then present it in the view that way rather than using innerHTML. Your compare method can then simply use the objects from the scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105842/discussion-between-anton-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 0):

[document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns  a single object and not an array.

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) need an array in odrer to operate it.

`forEach` method is not defined for object but it is defined for  array.
So,that's why you getting an error

```
document.getElementById(...).forEach is not a function
```

EDIT1 :

do like this :

```
var leftInput =  document.getElementById('left-input')
leftInputIds[leftInput.id] = leftInput;
var rightInput =  document.getElementById('right-input')
rightInputIds[rightInput.id] = rightInput;
```

Comment: does it mean that instead of forEach I have to use usual 'for Loop'?

Comment: No.As I said it return single object and not an array of object.If you want to iterate the property of individual object you can use `for in`

Comment: hmm, I compared your code and my and found that I already define the same variable for  $scope.rightElement. I guess that to use variable should be better cause the comparing will start after loading the second variable, now it starts to compare before rendering the page